# Avoid bash splitting a strings array when copying it

Tags: arrays, bash

To keep my script simple, I use string variables as variable names to recover other variables (in this case, arrays):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ANDROID_BUILD_OPTIONS=("armeabi-v7a" "arm64-v8a")
ANDROID_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS=("Regular ARM 32-bit" "Regular ARM 64-bit")
ANDROID_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT=2
IOS_BUILD_OPTIONS=("base")
IOS_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS=("Basic xcode target (ignored on non-MacOS build)")
IOS_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT=1

# Initial print of the arrays
echo "- ANDROID_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS -"
i=0
while [ $i -lt ${ANDROID_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT} ]; do
    echo "[$i] Name: ${ANDROID_BUILD_OPTIONS[i]}, description: ${ANDROID_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS[i]}"
    i=$((i + 1))
done
echo "- IOS_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS -"
i=0
while [ $i -lt ${IOS_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT} ]; do
    echo "[$i] Name: ${IOS_BUILD_OPTIONS[i]}, description: ${IOS_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS[i]}"
    i=$((i + 1))
done
echo

for TARGET in ANDROID IOS; do
    varname="${TARGET}_BUILD_OPTIONS[@]"
    TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS=${!varname}
    varname="${TARGET}_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS[@]"
    TARGET_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS=${!varname}
    varname="${TARGET}_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT"
    TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT=${!varname}

    echo "- TARGET_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS (${TARGET}) -"
    i=0
    while [ $i -lt ${TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT} ]; do
        echo "[$i] Name: ${TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS[i]}, description: ${TARGET_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS[i]}"
        i=$((i + 1))
    done
done
```

The above script produces the following output:

```
- ANDROID_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS -
[0] Name: armeabi-v7a, description: Regular ARM 32-bit
[1] Name: arm64-v8a, description: Regular ARM 64-bit
- IOS_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS -
[0] Name: base, description: Basic xcode target (ignored on non-MacOS build)

- TARGET_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS (ANDROID) -
[0] Name: armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a, description: Regular ARM 32-bit Regular ARM 64-bit
[1] Name: , description: 
- TARGET_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS (IOS) -
[0] Name: base, description: Basic xcode target (ignored on non-MacOS build)
```

As you can see in the output, the original arrays are properly assembled and their content is correctly displayed. But after the variable name substitution and the array copy, the content is assembled as one big string... Which completely destroys the content of the array since in this case it contains IFS-separated values (' '/space by default).

I've then tried another way, and I don't understand why this one doesn't work. I basically create `TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS` as a completely new array, then iterate over `ANDROID/IOS_BUILD_OPTIONS`'s content one element at a time, and copy it. Here is the updated code:

```
TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS=()
TARGET_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS=()
if [ "${TARGET}" = "ANDROID" ]; then
    COUNTER=0
    while [ "${COUNTER}" -lt "${ANDROID_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT}" ]; do
        TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS+=(${ANDROID_BUILD_OPTIONS[COUNTER]})
        TARGET_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS+=(${ANDROID_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS[COUNTER]})
        COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))
    done
else
    COUNTER=0
    while [ "${COUNTER}" -lt "${IOS_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT}" ]; do
        TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS+=(${IOS_BUILD_OPTIONS[COUNTER]})
        TARGET_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS+=(${IOS_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS[COUNTER]})
        COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))
    done
fi
```

And to my surprise... This doesn't work either. It seems to iterate over the strings, one word at a time:

```
- ANDROID_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS -
[0] Name: armeabi-v7a, description: Regular ARM 32-bit
[1] Name: arm64-v8a, description: Regular ARM 64-bit
- IOS_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS -
[0] Name: base, description: Basic xcode target (ignored on non-MacOS build)

- TARGET_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS (ANDROID) -
[0] Name: armeabi-v7a, description: Regular
[1] Name: arm64-v8a, description: ARM
- TARGET_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS (IOS) -
[0] Name: base, description: Basic
```

What's very surprising it that's it's the same piece of code used for the print earlier. Here are the two pieces of code next to each other:

```
# Correctly prints the complete strings one array element after the other
COUNTER=0
while [ $COUNTER -lt ${ANDROID_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT} ]; do
    echo "$COUNTER: ${ANDROID_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS[COUNTER]}"
    echo "$i: ${ANDROID_BUILD_OPTIONS[i]}, ${ANDROID_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS[i]}"
    COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))
done
# Copies the element one word by one word, using ' '/space as a separator?
COUNTER=0
while [ "${COUNTER}" -lt "${ANDROID_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT}" ]; do
    TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS+=(${ANDROID_BUILD_OPTIONS[COUNTER]})
    TARGET_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS+=(${ANDROID_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS[COUNTER]})
    COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))
done
```

Does anyone have any idea what's happening under the hood? How can I achieve the behavior I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS=${!varname}` - because you assemble them in one variable. Did you mean to make it an array? `TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS=("${!varname}")`? I think this script would be just simpler with a simple csv input file or as an associative array. `while [ $i -lt ${IOS_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT} ]; do` would be simpler as `for ((i=0;i < ${#IOS_BUILD_OPTIONS}; ++i))`, there is `${#array}` that allows you to get the count of elements in an arary, no need to `..._COUNT` variables.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I was testing things with this snippet. Putting parenthesis around it unfortunately doesn't change the result (which is also weird). It would indeed be simpler but I'm using already existing JSON files that I cannot modify. I also just found how to properly do what I wanted (IFS had something to do with the strange behavior), I'm going to post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have expanded the whole array content as a single string to the variable `TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS` instead of an array. i.e, `TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS="${!varname}` will treat the contents as a single string.

After this statement `varname="${TARGET}_BUILD_OPTIONS[@]"` , the `varname` becomes `ANDROID_BUILD_OPTIONS[@]` . So when you give `TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS="${!varname}"` it will be set as `TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS=armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a`.

On the other hand, When you give `TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS=("${!variable}")` , it will indeed be treated as an array `TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS=(armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a)`

Therefore, if you expand it as an array (setting `TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS=("${!varname}")`), then your script will work.

```
for TARGET in ANDROID IOS; do
    varname="${TARGET}_BUILD_OPTIONS[@]"
    TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS=("${!varname}")
    varname="${TARGET}_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS[@]"
    TARGET_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS=("${!varname}")
    varname="${TARGET}_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT"
    TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT=${!varname}

    echo "- TARGET_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS (${TARGET}) -"
    i=0
    while [ $i -lt ${TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT} ]; do
        echo "[$i] Name: ${TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS[i]}, description: ${TARGET_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS[i]}"
        i=$((i + 1))
    done
done
```

Comment: I didn't think about this option... I'll try and report back. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I can confirm that this does, indeed, work. I don't fully understand why the strings are conserved even though they're passed between `"..."`. I expected it to have the same behavior as my first try, i.e. transforming the array into one big string.

Comment: It is because after this statement  `varname="${TARGET}_BUILD_OPTIONS[@]"` , if you echo  `varname ` then it will output as  `ANDROID_BUILD_OPTIONS[@] `. So when you give  `("${!variable}") `, it will indeed expand to the content of the array  `(armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a) `

Answer (score 0):

The second method (creating an empty array and pushing items into it one by one) works, but `IFS` needs to be unset first, though I don't fully understand why.

```
        IFS=
        if [ "${TARGET}" = "ANDROID" ]; then
            COUNTER=0
            while [ "${COUNTER}" -lt "${ANDROID_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT}" ]; do
                TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS+=(${ANDROID_BUILD_OPTIONS[COUNTER]})
                TARGET_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS+=(${ANDROID_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS[COUNTER]})
                COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))
            done
        else
            COUNTER=0
            while [ "${COUNTER}" -lt "${IOS_BUILD_OPTIONS_COUNT}" ]; do
                TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS+=(${IOS_BUILD_OPTIONS[COUNTER]})
                TARGET_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS+=(${IOS_BUILD_DESCRIPTIONS[COUNTER]})
                COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))
            done
        fi
        IFS="${OLD_IFS}"
```

With correct values in the arrays, the `_COUNT` variables can be discarded as well, as `${#ARRAY_NAME[@]}` will return its size.

Comment: I think rather that the initial cause is the missing double quotes for example : `TARGET_BUILD_OPTIONS+=("${ANDROID_BUILD_OPTIONS[COUNTER]}")`